# Get data if foreign key is NULL or NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables *client* and *jobs*.

In client table i have a foreign key *job_id* who get *title* in jobs.

But my job_id can be NULL or NOT NULL.

I want to get *title* if *job_id* IS NOT NULL and get NULL if *job_id* is NULL.

I try this request with IF() but this doesn't works

```
SELECT c.*, j.titre_poste FROM client c JOIN jobs j ON IF(c.job_id IS NOT NULL, c.job_id, c.job_id=j.id) WHERE c.archive=0
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Sample data and desired result would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want all rows from `client` even if there is no match. in `jobs`  That suggests a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.*, j.titre_poste
FROM client c LEFT JOIN
     jobs j
     ON c.job_id = j.id
WHERE c.archive = 0
```